# custom post types and template names

Tags: php, wordpress

ive registered two custom post types in my website. one called property_sales and one called property_rentals.

I am displaying a few of these posts on my home page but would also like to point to the archive page in my sites main menu, as I only want to display 3 on the home page.

my question is would I then just call this file archive-property_sales.php (or rentals) and is the path to it simply www.mysite/property_sales?

Comment: Show some code that you are having problems with.

Comment: i'm not having problems with code, I was just wondering about naming the file correctly so that wordpress knows its the archive page for that custom post type :)

Comment: StackOverflow is more related to programming and coding problems.  You can try at Stackexchange/programmers or superuser.

Comment: didnt get your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andi, Your php file naming convention is right and as per the word press norms. Accessing of the archive files are also right.

in case your page is not visible than try the steps below to access the page.

1. Login to your WordPress admin.
2. Go to Settings -> Permalinks.
3. And under Common Settings, let’s use Post name.
4. Then click ‘Save Changes’
5. Now open any custom post type in the browser. You should see the URL in the form of:

   www.mysite/post-type/

   and in your case it would be.

   www.mysite/property_sales/

Comment: Thank you - i also realised I was not using the slug, just the custom-post name - not sure if that should make a difference but it did!

Answer (score 0):

Login to your WordPress admin.

Go to Settings -> Permalinks.

And under Custom Structure, use /%postname%